# Add Unique Id to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

How do I add a uniqueId for each entry to Firebase on a push? Right now my code looks like:

```
      this.games.push({
                        game_name: data.gameName,
                        number_of_players: data.number_of_players,
                        random_id: this.randomId,
                        admin: data.admin,
                        first_name: data.your_name,
                        player_array: [this.combinePlayerName(this.firstName, this.admin)] 
                     })
```

I'm using AngularFire2 and grabbing a database reference to this.games:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, af: AngularFire) {
    this.games = af.database.list('/games');
    this.ids = af.database.list('/games/random_id');
}
```

How do I push to the DB and instead of getting a list that looks like this with randomly generated Id's:

[image]

I get a list of intentional Id's that I have knowledge of and can select in the client code?

Comment: What do you mean by "have knowledge of"? Is there something in particular you want to do with the IDs before or after the push? Anyway, the push IDs are not entirely random, their initial component is a timestamp: https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11

Comment: o really? yes the wording is a bit confusing there, I want to give them Id's like: 331, 123 or 554 rather than: KbaZqVQBp580Zzt4Uty and the others in that list

Comment: You can just add them using [`set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) or [`update`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) with any ID you like as the key, but the onus is then on you to ensure the keys are unique. Typically, the use of push is encouraged for that reason.

Comment: I'm ok to use push, but how would I query for something within the list of games without using KbaZqVQBp580Zzt4Uty?

Comment: You can query using any of the child values: `game_name`, `first_name`, etc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes that makes sense I'm trying to pass in a function right now to search by gameId but can't compile though that may be another ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this:

**Get the push-id and store it in another node :**

There is a way to get the current push-id in AngularFire push method. So you can change the "randomly generated ids" to the ids that you "have knowledge of".

```
this.games.push({
   game_name: data.gameName,
   number_of_players: data.number_of_players,
   random_id: this.randomId,
   admin: data.admin,
   first_name: data.your_name,
   player_array: [this.combinePlayerName(this.firstName, this.admin)] 
}).then((game) => {
   this.ids.push(game.key);
})
```

**Other than this, you can actually change the push key by using the set method instead of push:**

```
this.af.database.object("games/"+this.randomId).set({
      game_name: data.gameName,
      number_of_players: data.number_of_players,
      random_id: this.randomId,
      admin: data.admin,
      first_name: data.your_name,
      player_array: [this.combinePlayerName(this.firstName, this.admin)]
    })
```

Where af contains the injected AngularFire module

```
 constructor(public af : AngularFire) { }
```

Even though this method works fine, it gives you another task of creating the unique ids, a task that firebase can do for you from the first method.

Also, as mentioned in the comments above, you can query your list by using the **random_id** child node.